# Lipschitz continuity of matrix product

Tags: matrices, normed-spaces, lipschitz-functions

Let $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$ and define the matrix functions $A:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^{m\times p}$ and $B:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}^{p\times p}$. Define $F(x) = A(x)\left[B(x)\right]^{-1}A(x)^\top\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$. I am interesting in showing that $F(x)$ is Lipschitz continuous, that is, I want to show that there exists some $L_F>0$ such that,
\begin{align*}
\|F(x) - F(y)\|\le L_F\|x-y\|
\end{align*}
Is showing that $A(x)$ and $B(x)$ are bounded functions of $x$ and Lipschitz with respect to some (any, because of norm equivalence) matrix norm sufficient for showing that $F(x)$ is Lipschitz?

Comment: Since you invert $B$, you need that $x \mapsto [B(x)]^{-1}$ is Lipschitz. For that, $B(x)$ must stay away from the set of non-invertible matrices.

Comment: @DanielFischer Thanks! I actually know that $B(x)$ is invertible for all $x$. I suppose the proof follows pretty directly from this added piece of information?

Comment: That's one part, but if $B(x)$ comes too close to the non-invertible matrices, that can destroy Lipschitz-continuity. Consider $p = 1$ for simplicity. Then since $b \mapsto \frac{1}{b}$ isn't Lipschitz, the map $x \mapsto B(x)^{-1}$ won't be Lipschitz if $B(x)$ comes too close to $0$.

Comment: @DanielFischer If I were to ensure that the domain of $B(x)$ in the one dimensional case was, say, $[\varepsilon,\infty)$ for some small $\varepsilon>0$ then wouldn't the function still be Lipschitz, just with a very large (but finite) Lipschitz constant? Can you formalize what you mean by 'too close'?

Comment: The range of $B(x)$ is more important than the domain. If the range of $B$ is (contained in) $[\varepsilon, +\infty)$, then inversion is Lipschitz on the range, and hence the Lipschitz-continuity of $B$ implies that of $x \mapsto [B(x)]^{-1}$.